# How do I execute an 'after_save' if a record is brand new, but a `before_save` if it isn't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `before_save` that requires the record to have been created/saved before.

Is there anyway for me to execute a `before_save` if the record is not `new`, but a `after_save` if it is?

**Edit 1**

This is my method and callback:

```
after_save :check_or_update_max_tree_depth

  def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
    self.max_tree_depth = self.last_depth
  end

  def last_depth
    if child_ids.empty?
      return root.max_tree_depth
    else
      return children.map{|c| c.last_depth}.max
    end
  end
```

After a new record is created, it doesn't save the `max_tree_depth` attribute. This is an example of a new record that was just created:

```
[155] pry(main)> p = Post.last
  Post Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"   ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Post id: 63, title: "JPS counter sues", photo: nil, body: "JPS has officially filed a countersuit on crashees...", created_at: "2015-01-05 05:30:39", updated_at: "2015-01-05 05:30:39", user_id: 3, ancestry: "46/54/59", file: nil, status: 1, slug: "jps-counter-sues", publication_status: 1, has_eyewitness: false, youtube_embed_code: "", soundcloud_embed_code: "", ancestry_depth: 3, max_tree_depth: nil>
[156] pry(main)> p.last_depth
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."ancestry" = '46/54/59/63'
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 46]]
=> 4
[157] pry(main)> p.child_ids
  Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "posts"."id" FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."ancestry" = '46/54/59/63'
=> []
[158] pry(main)> p.root.max_tree_depth
  Post Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 46]]
=> 4
[159] pry(main)> p.max_tree_depth
=> nil
```

Notice that everything else seems to be returning the right values. It is just that whenever a new record is created, it doesn't save it.

If I used a `before_save`, it would update the attribute correctly - but only on existing records. On brand new records, that have not been saved before, `ancestry gem` would throw a fit.

Comment: Why don't you go for after_create instead of after_save if you want to execute that callback only if record is new

Comment: you can check `new_record?`

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar if I do an `after_save`, and I have an assignment function - like `self.max_tree_depth = self.last_depth` will it save that assignment?

Comment: You mean to say in after_save or after_create?

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar `after_save`. i.e. the record has been saved and I do an assignment statement. In order for that change to be executed it would have to execute that callback, no? So unless I use something to prevent that callback from being executed, it won't save that record, correct?

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar Nevermind..I got it.

Comment: I was suggesting to use after_create instead of after_save as after_create will be invoked only when we create record first time. And for calling save in after_save callback you can use update_column method self.update_column(self.max_tree_depth,self.last_depth) this will not call save callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should accomplish what you want:

```
before_save :method_name
after_save :method_name

private

def method_name
  if new_record? || @already_ran
    @already_ran = nil # using 'remove_instance_variable' would be better
    return 
  end

  # your method's original code

  @already_ran = true # pick a better variable name
end
```

`@already_ran` is simply to ensure that the same method isn't called before saving AND after saving. If it's safe to run it twice, before and after saving, then you can simplify things like so:

```
before_save :method_name
after_save :method_name

private

def method_name
  return if new_record?
  # your method's original code
end
```

Or, depending on your use-case, you could just keep the `after_save` and remove the `before_save` altogether. But I'm assuming that you've already considered other simplification options e.g. having a single `after_save` or `after_create` callback.

Comment: I like this idea. When would `@already_ran` be reset though? I would think it would be reset once the operation is over, no? i.e. Meaning, the `before_save` executes it...then sets it to `true`, then that operation comes to an end (aka `@already_ran` resets), the record is saved and the `after_save` is then run again. If that is the case, wouldn't it defeat the purpose of the first version. I really like the second one though.

Comment: Look at the `new_record? || @already_ran` condition in the first method. Notice that the instance variable is being reset based on this condition.

Comment: How do I use an `after_save` to modify an attribute of the record, without ending up in an infinite loop? I have updated the question with the attribute I want to update and exactly what my method will be.

Comment: In your method: `self.class.where(id: self.id).update_all(column: new_value)`

Comment: What about when a record is deleted. I tried using `update_columns(column: new_value)` and I am getting this error: `cannot update on a new record object`

Comment: Sounds like a new problem than the original question. Look for an existing question. If you can't find one, then post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is reload the object for persistence

```
after_save :check_or_update_max_tree_depth

def check_or_update_max_tree_depth
  self.reload
  self.max_tree_depth = self.last_depth
  self.save
end

def last_depth
  if child_ids.empty?
    return root.max_tree_depth
  else
    return children.map{|c| c.last_depth}.max
  end
end
```